# Is there a way to programmatically launch samsung's device maintenance from my app?

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

In lieu of a cache wipe functionality (since normal apps can't get access to 3rd party app cache directories) I want to launch the device maintenance storage screen built into Samsung phones. What is the package name i need to put for the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if manufactorer is samsung:

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("samsung"))
```

then

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setPackage("com.samsung.android.lool"));
```

Comment: How did you find out it was lool? Just looking at logs when you launched the app or is there documentation from Samsung I can look at? I'd like to support more manufacturers that have a similar app so having a clue on where to look would be helpful

Comment: What about **Huawei**?